# Unable to log in to localhost wp-admin page on XAMPP server

Tags: wp-admin, localhost, xampp

I am a newbie who recently start working on XAMPP and I am unable to access wp-admin on XAMPP server localhost.  While installing WordPress, it asked me for user name and password too but when I am trying to access wp-admin with username and password, it says "INVALID USER NAME". As far as I know, I am putting the correct username and password here.

Please suggest how to login back and where will I get the correct user details.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the caps lock key?

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into the same problem but I fixed it by doing the following: 
**1.** Go back to phpmyadmin (The url should be similar to this : **http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/**)
**2.** Click your database name in order to display tables
**3.** Choose the table wp_users (if you've changed the wp_ prefix to something else when installing wordpress,
 then it should be **"yourNewPrefix_users"**.) and click on it to open rows.
**4.** You will just notice that it has only one row. What you have to do is to click **"edit"** in order to edit columns 
**5.** Some columns will pop up. Only one column causes the password issue: the column name is as follow:
 user_pass   |  varchar(255)  |   box (please click on it and select **MD5**  |  box (just delete whatever
 you see in that box) and type any password (it may be your old password that did not work for you
 previously while attempting to login) and hit **Go** to save your changes.
**6.** go back to your browser now and try to login again to wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

You could also just go to file manager on your system, navigate to your xamp wordpress directory, open wp-config.php and see what the actual saved username and password are.

Comment: The username/password saved in `wp-config.php` would gain you access to the database, but that wouldn't necessarily be the same as your WP login.